# Unable to modify some internal styles of Material UI's <Dialog> component

Tags: css, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I'm trying to apply some reasonably simple styles to my `<Dialog>` component.  In this case, I am trying to round the corners with a border radius.  Here are some simple inline styles that I'd like to use to override the default `<Dialog>` styles:

```
let overrideStyles = {
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
  borderRadiusTopLeft: '4px',
  borderRadiusTopRight: '4px',
};
```

`<Dialog>` provides a wide variety of possibilities for overriding internal styles.  These include `bodyStyle`, `contentStyle`, `style`, `titleStyle`, `overlayStyle`, and `actionsContainerStyle`.  I decided to try to apply these styles to *each* one.

```
<Dialog
  bodyStyle={overrideStyles}
  contentStyle={overrideStyles}
  style={overrideStyles}
  titleStyle={overrideStyles}
  overlayStyle={overrideStyles}
  actionsContainerStyle={overrideStyles}
  modal={overrideStyles}
>
  <TestPanel/>
</Dialog>
```

When I render my `TestPanel`, it ends up looking like this:

[image: Test panel]

Notice the corners, where my border radius has not been applied... I opened up the inspector and noticed the following div:

[image: Div without style]

If I apply the border radius styling to the highlighted div, the dialog will have its corners rounded as expected.  Which leads me to my question...

How do I override the styles of Material UI's `<Dialog>` component to apply rounded corners as my CSS is attempting?

Comment: It's tricky and makes you wonder why they don;t just apply some classes/sub-classes to these components (but that's a different issue covered in other posts) - However you can either add your own class className="my-dialog" and then you can do .my-dialog > div:first-of-type { border-radius: 4px } - alternatively add overflow:hidden to your outer div although that could have other unexpected behaviour of course... In conclusion they're not nice to style.

Answer (score 11):

I solved it with paperProps property.

```
<Dialog   PaperProps={{
    style: { borderRadius: 2 }   }}
  >   .... </Dialog>
```

This perfeclty worked **for me**

Comment: Right answer right here. The `PaperProps` prop appears in the Dialog API in Material UI docs.

Answer (score 9):

You can override styles like below.

```
const styles = { 
  root: { }
  paper: { borderRadius: 15 } 
} 

// ... 

<Dialog classes={{ 
    root: classes.root, 
    paper: classes.paper 
}}>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: You don't include how to set the variable "classes" ( as you used in "classes.root) in your answer.  Your answer is half finished.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Material UI isn't supremely style-friendly. In this case, there's no prop you can override to change the border-radius, so we've got to apply our own class:

```js
let headerStyles = {
  color: 'white',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: 24,
  backgroundColor: '#3B8DBC',
  padding: 20,
  borderTopLeftRadius: 4,
  borderTopRightRadius: 4
};

let bodyStyles = {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  padding: 10,
  height: 200
};

<Dialog className='test'>
  <div style={headerStyles}>Testing</div>
  <div style={bodyStyles}>5:43pm</div>
</Dialog>
```

Then style that class, and, yes, the border-radius has to be set on both of the below CSS classes as well as the TestPanel header:

```
 /* Some rules use !important because Material UI sets them by default */
.test > div > div {
  background-color: #3B8DBC;  /* Same background-color as TestPanel */
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.test > div > div > div {
  /* Not overriding the color and border radius here too result in your changes
     not being visible. */
  background-color: inherit !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
}

.test > div > div > div > div {
  /* This div is the topmost padding between the modal content and the edge
     of the modal */
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

This ends up looking like what you want:
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg1cp.png)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can override `<Dialog />` styles globally in your application when creating your theme object. The `paper` key of `MuiDialog` will let you target the border-radius.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiDialog: {
      paper: {
        borderTopLeftRadius: '4px',
        borderTopRightRadius: '4px'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Dialog - CSS api](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#css)
[Material UI Theming](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)

Comment: This is the proper way of handling and it should be considered like the best answer.

Comment: This looks like proper way but it's not working in https://zenoo.github.io/mui-theme-creator/?firstName=&lastName=&email=&password=#Dialog

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is not working for me. I tried this and it work perfect for me:

```
sx={{
    "& .MuiDialog-container": {
    "& .MuiPaper-root": {
      width: "100%",
      maxWidth: "740px",
      borderRadius: "8px"
        }
      },
    }}
```